# How to group similar numbers with ranges/conditions and merge IDs using dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, sorting, iteration

Please, I have a dataframe that is listed in ascending order. My goal is to average similar numbers (numbers that are within 10% of each other in ‘both directions’) and concate their ‘Bell’ name together. For example, the image shows the input and output dataframe. I tried coding it but I stuck on how to progress.

[image: dataframe]

```
   def full_data_compare(self, df_full = pd.DataFrame()):
       for k in range(df_full): #current rows
           for j in range(df_full): #future rows
               if int(df_full['Size'][k]) - int(df_full['Size'][k])*(1/10) <= int(df_full['Size'][j]) <= int(df_full['Size'][k]) + int(df_full['Size'][k])*(1/10) & int(df_full['Size'][k]) - int(df_full['Size'][k])*(1/10) <= int(df_full['Size'][j]) <= int(df_full['Size'][k]) + int(df_full['Size'][k])*(1/10):
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put the input/output dataframe as text instead of images (so we can copy-paste it)?

Comment: How do you define "*within 10% of each other*"? Are 90 and 100 matching the condition even if 90*1.1=99? Or would you need at least 90.91/100?

Comment: Your dataframe is not currently in ascending order, as the final value is less than the value before it.

Comment: Also, if you had 100 rows with Size values of `1,2,...,100` and Bell vlaues of `A1,A2,...,A100`, what result would you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you really want to check in both directions that the consecutive values are within 10%, you need to compute two Series with `pct_change`. Then use it to `groupby.agg`:

```
#df = df.sort_values(by='Size') for non-consecutive grouping

m1 = df['Size'].pct_change().abs().gt(0.1)
m2 = df['Size'].pct_change(-1).abs().shift().gt(0.1)

out = (df
 .groupby((m1|m2).cumsum())
 .agg({'Bell': ' '.join, 'Size': 'mean'})
)
```

*NB. If you want to group non-consecutive values, you first need to sort them: `sort_values(by='Size')`*

Output:

```
          Bell          Size
Size                        
0        A1 A2   1493.500000
1     A1 A2 A3   5191.333333
2     A1 A3 A2  35785.333333
3           A2  45968.000000
4           A1  78486.000000
5           A3  41205.000000
```

Comment: Perfect Thank you! Where can i learn more about using pandas and avoiding for loops?